# How to send emails connecting to the SMTP server directly?

Tags: php, linux

I do not want to use `mail()` to send e-mail. I would like to connect to the SMTP server directly.

Is there a class to do this job?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftMailer does this.

http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.introduction.html) can do this for you:

```
$tr = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('mail.example.com');
Zend_Mail::setDefaultTransport($tr);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
$mail->addTo('studio@example.com', 'Test');
$mail->setFrom('studio@example.com', 'Test');
$mail->setSubject('Subject');
$mail->setBodyText('...Your message here...');
$mail->send();
```

Comment: In the past, anything prefixed `Zend_` had a tendency to depend on eeeeverything in the rest of the Zend framework, is this still the case?

Comment: @Piskvor No, Zend Framework is a loosely-coupled component library. You can pick just the components you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of existing smtp classes [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/searchtag/smtp/by/package/tag/smtp/)

Comment: You should provide a recommendation or two, if you are going to link to such a list.  A couple of those are bound to be terrible.

Comment: [Secure SMTP client](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5767-PHP-Send-messages-via-SMTP-server-with-authentication.html) and [Send mail from any SMTP server](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5657-PHP-Compose-and-send-e-mail-messages-via-SMTP.html) will do the job perfectly